# SQL Query displaying only 14 out of 28 expected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

My below SQL query is supposed to display 28 results, however it only displays 14.

I think its something to do with my joins, one of the tables has no records at all for the missing results but I expect it to display as NULL if thats the case:

```
SELECT c.Name, u.Id, u.From, u.Send, COUNT(al.Id) as Total
FROM Auction_Location al
LEFT JOIN US u ON u.Id = al.CId
LEFT JOIN City c ON c.Id = u.CityId 
WHERE al.CityId IN (983, 984)
GROUP BY c.Name, u.Id, u.From, u.Send
ORDER BY c.Name ASC;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` keys are not consistent (because of `name`).

Comment: i have edited the query

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join.  Move the condition to an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT b.Name, b.Id, b.First, b.Second, COUNT(c.Id) as Total
FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN 
     Table2 b
     ON b.Id = a.MyId LEFT JOIN
     Table3 c
     ON c.Id = b.CId  AND c.Id IN (9, 10)
GROUP BY b.Name, b.Id, b.First, b.Second
ORDER BY b.Name ASC;
```

Note that I changed the `COUNT()` so it counts matches in `table3` rather than `table1`.  And I fixed the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses so they match.

Comment: have edited my query, i was seeing results outside of  the specified CityId's, i was getting roughly 200 results instead of 28, although I was seeing nulls